# How to restrict other shipping methods - Magento

Tags: magento, restriction

By `$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');` method I can create a new shipping rate. But How can I restrict other shipping methods in this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab All active shipping methods, loop through each one, and see if it matches your desired one

```
$activeCarriers = Mage::getModel('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
foreach($activeCarriers as $code => $method) {
    if($code == 'yourcode') {
         $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    }

}
```